# Could I turn a classification problem into regression problem by encoding the classes?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, classification

If all categorical labels could be represented in numerical values, does it means that I could use regression models on any classification tasks by encode the categorical labels as number?

I'm recently working on an binary classification problem that have two output type: '0' for positive and '1' for negative. I've used Random-Forest-Classifier to solve this, but I see others use Random-Forest-Regressor for the same problem. After thinking, it makes sense to me -- the final desired output is continuous value, and I could train a regression model to get predicted continuous value which represents the output class.

This make me think about if it's possible to use regression model on other classification tasks. For example:

To classify two images of 'cat' and 'dog', I use LabelEncoder to encode it as 0 and 1, then it becomes an regression problem.

Hope my question is clear, thanks for helping!

Comment: Flagged as a question that should be asked at stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not. you can not define Cat < Dog or Dog < Cat. Regression works on that assumption. when you use regression for binary classification like logistic regression it is actually predicting the probability of a class which is a continuous variable.

Comment: Why? What happens if one builds a regular regression on a binary dependent variable?

Comment: The linear regression model is based on an assumption that the outcome Y is continuous, with errors (after removing systematic variation in mean due to covariates X_{1},.., X_{p}) which are normally distributed. If the outcome variable is binary this assumption is clearly violated, and so, in general, we might expect our inferences to be invalid.

Comment: I see, so for binary classification task the output is discrete, to optimize the model by gradient descent don't make sense. Class '1' shouldn't be larger than class '0', that's why we shouldn't use an regression model on a classification task. I just see someone use random forest regression tree on a binary classification task, so I've this question. Thanks!